# Conditional display of a key in the array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, key

How do I know if a key in an array is true? If not, then don't use this

```
[0] => array
(
[id] => 1
[some_key] => something
)

[1] => array
(
[id] => 2
)

[2] => array
(
[id] => 3
[some_key] => something
)

foreach($array as $value){
$id = $value->id;
if($value->some_key === TRUE){
$some_key = $value->some_key; //some may have this key, some may not
}
}
```

Not sure what is the proper statement to check if this array has that `some_key`. If I don't have a check, it will output an error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the keys you want to check for or the value? Because you keep saying keys, but your checking for a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isset()` function to see if a variable is set.

```
foreach($array as $value){
    $id = $value->id;
    if(isset($value->some_key)){
        $some_key = $value->some_key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
isset($array[$some_key])
```

It will return true if the array $array has an index $some_key, which can be a string or an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned isset(), which *mostly* works. It will fail if the value under the key is null, however:

```
$test = array('sampleKey' => null);
isset($test['sampleKey']); // returns false
```

If this case is important for you to test, there's an explicit array_key_exists() function which handles it correctly:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Good point. However, it's worth noting that this won't work on objects. For objects you need to use the property_exists() function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate($array)
{
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if( !array_key_exists('id', $val) ) return false;
        if( !array_key_exists('some_key', $val) ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```